# 100% CPU load after sending a Mail via poco and ssl

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I try to send a mail via lib poco and ssl. I use a very simple example code because the functionality is sufficient for me.
The code is working, so it does want I wanted him to do, but unfortunately the cpu load raised to 100% after sending a mail. This happened every time, so I think I've made a mistake inside the code. Could anybody give me a hint to help me? Thanks a lot.

```
void <myclass>::sendMessageSSL() {
    string to = "<toMail>";
    string from = "<from>";
    string subject = "Subject";
    subject = MailMessage::encodeWord(subject, "UTF-8");
    string content = "Content";
    MailMessage message;
    message.setSender(from);
    message.addRecipient(MailRecipient(MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, to));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    message.setContent(content, MailMessage::ENCODING_8BIT);
    try {
         SecureSMTPClientSession session(host_out, port_out);
         session.open();
         // Initialize the NetSSL library, as well as the underlying OpenSSL libraries
         initializeSSL();
         SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrHandler =
            new AcceptCertificateHandler(false);
         Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "",
            Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true,
            "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
         SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, ptrHandler, ptrContext);
         try {
             // TLS begins with an unsecured connection
             session.login();
             // Upgrades to secured connection once the information is sent
             if (session.startTLS(ptrContext)) {
            session.login(SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, user, pass);
            session.sendMessage(message);
             }
             session.close();
             uninitializeSSL();
          } catch (SMTPException &e) {
             cerr << e.displayText() << endl;
             session.close();
             uninitializeSSL();
          }
     } catch (NetException &e) {
         cerr << e.displayText() << endl;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have solved this already. Better late than never? I just came across your question. I have a working program similar to yours that does not have a 100% cpu issue. I will share the differences of my code and what you have posted.

First off, I'm passing a PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler instead of a null pointer to initializeClient. See below:

```
    SharedPtr<PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> ptrPrivKeyPassHandler = new KeyConsoleHandler(false);
    SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrInvalidCertHandler = new AcceptCertificateHandler(false);
    Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Context::VERIFY_RELAXED,
        9, true, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

    SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(ptrPrivKeyPassHandler, ptrInvalidCertHandler, ptrContext);
```

Secondly, I'm making absolutely sure to close the session and uninitialize the SSL engine. I do this by putting these two commands outside and below the try/catch area so that they are always executed. If you get a NetException, it looks like your code won't execute these two statements.

```
    session.close();
    uninitializeSSL();
```